# Magento 2.2 some JS files are not loading in production mode

Tags: multistore, magento2.2.2, requirejs, production-mode, ui

In **Magento 2.2.2** when setting website into **production** mode the following **files are not loading,** due to which my store switcher and other ui functions are not working in production mode:

- http://website.com/static/frontend/vendor/theme/en_US/jquery/ui.js
- http://website.com/static/frontend/vendor/theme/en_US/jquery/validate.js
- http://website.com/static/frontend/vendor/theme/en_US/jquery/jquery-storageapi.js

All the CSS and Fonts are loading properly in both production as well as developer mode.

**Important**:
I was not able to find these js files in developer mode when checked the network tab of inspector.

Can someone tell me where to look for errors?

> Update 1:

I have checked and found that these js file errors are only found in default (pt_BR) Store. When I have checked it for other store(en_US) there were no errors and everything is working fine in this store.

> Update 2:

When I have tried `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US pt_BR` then these js file error occurred in both the stores.

P.S: There is nothing helpful in var logs.

Comment: I am also faced this issue and raised here, I am still looking for proper solution, but I solved it by setting mode as default, then everything works fine for me.

Comment: @jafarpinjar Still default mode is same as developer. I need to enable production mode.

Comment: It is not possible to set `default` Magento mode ! `production` or `developper`, a default one is just set by default when you install a Magento in the first time.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set `default` Magento **mode** ! `production` or `developper`, a `default` one is just set by default when you install a Magento in the first time.

Try this:

1. Remove the content of the bellow folders except the `.htaccess`

   > - var/cache
   > - var/page_cache
   > - var/view_preprocessed
   > - generated
   > - pub/static
2. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

More informations in [MAGENTO DEVDOCS](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html)

Comment: This still didn't worked for me. The 3 js files are still showing 404 in default store.

Comment: Try this : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f`

Comment: Yes I have tried `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US pt_BR -f` but still no change.

Comment: Your default config language is `en_US` ?

Comment: No, Default store language is `pt_BR` and I have just updated my question.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work ! try `rm -R pub/static/*` then `php bin/magento indexer:reindex ` then `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: Tried this, still no fix

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82702/discussion-between-wasiq-shahrukh-and-prince).

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. en_GB is my default. Deploy static content for both en_US and en_GB and jquery.min & plugins.min both do not exist in pub/static.